# Does "since then" mean "from then to NOW"?

Tags: reference

I learned that "since then" means "from then to **now**". So I guess it is wrong to use "since then" in my text because what I want to mean is "to 2019" and not "to now"?

> The amount of time the average household spent doing housework dropped
> significantly from 50 to 15 hours per week between 1920 and 1980.
> **Since then**, it experienced only a small decline to just over 10 hours a week in 2019.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, "since then" just means "since some initial time" and the final time is some reference point. If there is no other context, people will often assume that the reference point is "now", but it doesn't have to be. For example, the reference point can be a time in the past:

> **When I was in my twenties**, I thought often about my teenage years and about how much I had matured **since then**.

It can also be a time in the future:

> **When you begin your trip next week**, think about the clothes that you packed the previous day and whether the weather forecast has changed **since then**.

Your sentence doesn't work because when the reader encounters "since", there is no clear reference point, so he or she will assume that it is "now" and be surprised upon encountering "in 2019".<sup>1</sup> Here is one possible way to fix that:

> The amount of time the average household spent doing housework dropped significantly (from 50 to 15 hours per week) between 1920 and 1980. Afterward it experienced only a small decline (to just over 10 hours a week in 2019).

(I inserted parentheses around phrases that seemed to me to be nonrestrictive.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Another problem is that "since" usually implies a nonspecific time, so the reader expects not the simple past tense ("experienced") but the present perfect ("has experienced").

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you for your answers. @MarcInManhattan, do you mean the word **since** is causing the problem? How about **from then on**: The amount of time the average household spent doing housework dropped significantly between 1920 and 1980. **From then on**, it experienced only a small decline to just over 10 hours a week in 2019.

Comment: Also, what is this kind of transition word called? Time transition word?

Comment: @Learner110 The "on" implies to me that the decline continued until the present time, not just until 2019. Others might disagree. // I'm not sure which transition word you mean. ("Since"? "From"?) In any case, I don't usually distinguish among different types.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it means "from then to now". Or sometimes "from then, to now, and on into the foreseeable future".

> Sunak has been Prime Minister since October 25th.  (from then to now and probably into to near future)

In some cases (when used with past tenses) it means "from then to then"

> Truss who had been Prime minister since the 6th of September, resigned on the 25th of October.